# Flutter: how to remove the white background behind the keyboard when keyboard got activated

Tags: ios, flutter

I have a flutter app and I do experience a strange behaviour when the keyboard get activated in my iPhone. As you can see from the picture below there is a white background which appears under the keyboard while it is popping up...
Does anyone know how to set that background color???

[image]

**EDIT**:
Thanks for the suggestion to use `resizeToAvoidBottomPadding`. That command is deprecated and I have replaced with `resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false`. This has resolved the issue (yup!) and there is no more white background under the keyboard BUT it has created another strange effect. There is now a dark-blue bar above the keyboard. Check the next image... I have set an orange background color so you can see it better. You can also see that the floating button is shifted up which means the dark-blu bar is now between the keyboard and the scaffold. Do you know how I can get rid of that bar? this seems to be worst Thant the white background since it is taking precious screen space..

For reference the scaffold is nested in a CupertinoTabScaffold
[image]

Here is the most relevant part of my code

```
void main() async {
  Crashlytics.instance.enableInDevMode = true;

  FlutterError.onError = Crashlytics.instance.recordFlutterError;

  runApp(ChangeNotifierProvider<Data>(
    builder: (context) => Data(),
    child: new CupertinoApp(

      theme: CupertinoThemeData(
        barBackgroundColor: kColorPrimary,

        primaryColor:
            kColorText,
        textTheme: CupertinoTextThemeData(
          primaryColor:
              kColorText,
          navLargeTitleTextStyle: TextStyle(
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 70.0, color: kColorText),
        ),
      ),

      home: new CheckIfFirstTime(),
    ),
  ));
}

class CheckIfFirstTime extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CheckIfFirstTimeState createState() => _CheckIfFirstTimeState();
}

class _CheckIfFirstTimeState extends State<CheckIfFirstTime> {
  Future checkFirstSeen() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    bool _seen = (prefs.getBool('seen') ?? false);

    if (_seen) {
      Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
          new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => new HomeScreen()));
    } 
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    checkFirstSeen();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: kColorPrimary,
      body: Text(
        'loading...',
        style: kSendButtonTextStyle,
      ),
    );
  }
}



class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String id = 'home';

  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  int currentIndex = 0;

  void confirmPlatform() {
    if (Platform.isIOS)
      appData.isIOS = true;
    else
      appData.isIOS = false;
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    confirmPlatform();

  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CupertinoTabScaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      tabBar: CupertinoTabBar(
        backgroundColor: kColorPrimaryLight,
        items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.search),
            title: Text('Discover', style: TextStyle(fontFamily: kFontFamily)),
          ),

          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Badge(
                showBadge: Provider.of<Data>(context).filterCounter == 0
                    ? false
                    : true,
                badgeContent: Text(
                  Provider.of<Data>(context).filterCounter.toString(),
                  style: TextStyle(color: kColorText),
                ),
                child: Icon(Icons.filter_list)),
            title: Text('Filters', style: TextStyle(fontFamily: kFontFamily)),
          ),

          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.account_circle),
            title: Text('Me', style: TextStyle(fontFamily: kFontFamily)),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.assignment),
            title: Text('Stories', style: TextStyle(fontFamily: kFontFamily)),
          ),
//with badge
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Badge(
                showBadge: Provider.of<Data>(context).basketCounter == '0'
                    ? false
                    : true,
                badgeContent: Text(
                  Provider.of<Data>(context).basketCounter,
                  style: TextStyle(color: kColorText),
                ),
                child: Icon(Icons.shopping_cart)),
            title: Text('Basket', style: TextStyle(fontFamily: kFontFamily)),
          ), 
        ],
              ),
      tabBuilder: (context, index) {
        if (index == 0) {
          return CupertinoTabView(
            navigatorKey: firstTabNavKey,
            builder: (BuildContext context) => DiscoverScreenFinal(),
          );

        } else if (index == 1) {
          return CupertinoTabView(
            navigatorKey: secondTabNavKey,
            builder: (BuildContext context) => FilterScreen(),
          );
        } else if (index == 2) {
          return CupertinoTabView(
            navigatorKey: thirdTabNavKey,
            builder: (BuildContext context) => WelcomeScreen(),
          );
        } else if (index == 3) {
          return CupertinoTabView(
            navigatorKey: forthTabNavKey,
            builder: (BuildContext context) => Stories(),
          );
        }
        {
          return CupertinoTabView(
            navigatorKey: fifthTabNavKey,
            builder: (BuildContext context) => Basket(),
          );
        }
      },
    );
  }
}


class DiscoverScreenFinal extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DiscoverScreenFinalState createState() => _DiscoverScreenFinalState();
}

class _DiscoverScreenFinalState extends State<DiscoverScreenFinal> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TopBarAgnostic(
      text: 'Discover',
      style: kSendButtonTextStyle,
      firstIcon: Icon(Icons.blur_on),
      firstIconDestination: CameraApp(),
      scannerOn: true,
      secondtIcon: Icon(Icons.location_on),
      secondIconDestination: MapPage(),
      uniqueHeroTag: 'discover001a',
      child: Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
        backgroundColor: kColorPrimary,
        floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.endFloat,
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton.extended(
          backgroundColor: kColorAccent,
          onPressed: () {
            //…
          },
          label: Text(
            'To Favorites',
            style: kDescriptionTextStyle.copyWith(
                fontSize: kFontSizeSmall, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          ),
          icon: Icon(Icons.favorite),
        ),
        body: Container()
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I believe i know what's your issue, but I cant confirm it without a snippet of code. Could you provide some? Especially something explaining how exactly you are setting the dark-blue background in your layout.

Comment: Just a guess, what if you try to change backgroundColor in Main.storyboard?

Answer (score 9):

You have to use this line in Scaffold, it will adjust your view automatically when keyboard is appear and disappear.

```
resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false
```

Comment: this is good but it created another problem. see the edit in my post

Comment: Thank you so much, that worked for me. I was getting the background image going up every time when the keyboard shows up.

Comment: It is removed after flutter 2 what do you think can be used?

Comment: @MohammadHosein use resizeToAvoidBottomInset instead

Answer (score 2):

You could set a `backgroundColor` to the `Scaffold` to replace that white background.

This happens because the body of the `Scaffold` gets resized when you open the keyboard. If you want to avoid the resizing you could set `resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false` to the `Scaffold`.

Comment: this is good but it created another problem. see the edit in my post

Answer (score 2):

after flutter 2 use this in the Scaffold

```
resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
```

Answer (score 1):

Best solution is creating a `Stack widget` with two children: a `Container` for the background (color, gradient, background image...) and a `Scaffold` for the app content.

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
        children: [
      Container(
        decoration:  /* ... Background styles ... */,
      ),
      Scaffold(
          extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
          appBar: AppBar(backgroundColor: Colors.transparent, elevation: 0),
          body: Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 16, left: 16, right: 16),
              child: SafeArea(bottom: false, child: /* ... App content ... */))
      )
    ]);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can solve this problem by keeping Scaffold inside of Container, like this:

```
   Container(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      gradient: LinearGradient(
        begin: Alignment.topRight,
        end: Alignment(0.5, 0.3),
        colors: [
          Colors.red,
          Colors.green,
        ],
      ),
    ),
    child: Scaffold(/* ... rest of your code ... */)
  )
```

Comment: It does not work for me, maybe I have something weird somewhere

Answer (score 0):

if you are in develop app in java solve this by just adding  `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` in your activity present in the manifest file.
Thanks

Answer (score -1):

you can use

```
child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Color(0xff53ccb2),
```